# Taking derivatives of objective function with a binary variable to find minimum

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, binary-variable

I transform my minimization problem into one with only an objective function (no constraints). I only have one variable, which is binary.

- Can I derivate the objective and make it equal to 0 to find the objective values?
- If so, How? If you can send me an example, link, or a book to check how to derivate stuff like this, it would be amazing.

My objective function is as follows,

$$
\min_x \sum_{j\in J}\sum_{i \in I} C_{ij} \sum_{i'=\tau}^i X_{i'j}
$$

Added:
Let $\tau=min(0,i-5)$ for example. And $X_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ with $i,j \in IxJ$.

Comment: Maybe this [one](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2021/02/lagrangean-relaxation-for-assignment.html) can be helpful.

Comment: Can you say something about the signs, domains and dimensions of the variables?

Comment: Specifically, what is $\tau$ in the final summation?

Comment: Hi, X is binary with i,j in IxJ. And I  is a function of i, should have fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First order stationary point conditions will usually not help when your variables are discrete.

In this particular case, if $\tau$ is a constant (and assuming $x$ and $X$ are the same thing), the solution is trivial. Rewrite the objective as $$\min_X \sum_{i\in I : i \ge \tau}\sum_{j\in J} \left[ \sum_{k\in I : k\ge i} C_{kj} \right] X_{ij}.$$ Let $d_{ij} = \sum_{k\in I : k\ge i} C_{kj}.$ The optimal solution is found by inspection:$$X_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1 & d_{ij}<0\\
0\textrm{ or }1 & d_{ij}=0\\
0 & d_{ij}>0
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Nice! I ended with something similar but was not sure it was good. Do you know where I can find a mathematical justification? Like a paper of book or theorem? I need to cite it for a paper.

Comment: Sorry, no. I think I've encountered a mention in passing once or twice (an author pointing out the obvious solution), but I don't recall where, and in any case I would not consider such a mention worth citing. I would just state it in the paper as "obvious" or "by inspection".